# In Spock unit test mocked method is not being called

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, mocking, kotlin, spock

I'm trying to implement unit test using [Spock framework](http://spockframework.org/) this is what my test looks like:

```
    def setup() {
        scrollableResultsMock = Mock(ScrollableResults)
        paymentRepositoryMock = Mock(PaymentRepository)

        paymentRegistryService = new PaymentRegistryService(paymentRepositoryMock)
    }

    @Unroll
    def 'should correctly process'() {
        given:
        paymentRepositoryMock.findUnconfirmedTransactions(_ as LocalDate, _ as Days) >> scrollableResultsMock
        ...
    }
```

Here is class in which I'm trying to inject mocked object:

```
@Service
open class PaymentRegistryService
@Autowired
constructor(
        val paymentRepository: PaymentRepository
) {

    @Transactional
    open fun parseRegistryFileStream(input: InputStream): LinkedList<Pair<Long, String>> {
        ...
        val registry = paymentRepository.findUnconfirmedTransactions(start, PERIOD)
        ...
    }
}
```

While running test instead of calling my method real `paymentRepository` method is being called. I don't understand what could be the reason. `LocalDate` and `Days` are from [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) and finally this is `paymentRepository` class:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
open class PaymentRepository : AbstractRepository<Payment, Long>(Payment::class.java) {

    fun findUnconfirmedTransactions(start: LocalDate, days: Days): ScrollableResults = criteria().add(
            and(
                    eq("isConfirmed", false),
                    ge("transactionDateTime", start),
                    lt("transactionDateTime", start.plus(days))
            )).setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE).scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY)

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try this:

```
open fun findUnconfirmedTransactions(start: LocalDate, days: Days): ScrollableResults
```

Mocking needs to extend function and Spock won't be able to do so unless function is open in Kotlin.

Comment: Before this quick answer came I wanted to reproduce the problem and noted that your sample code does not show how the mock method is called in the test. So I had to make ssumptions on that, which is not nice. Next time please also describe how you use something, not just how you declare it. `...` is not very helpful here.

Comment: Thank you for your remark I'll try to foresee it in my questions but you could have just asked and I would have added that part of code to my question.

Comment: This also applies to Spock 1.3 - in order to mock Kotlin function, it has to be `open`.